# PHP Script on Apache reply on Post Request

Tags: php, apache, http

I want to send a post request from my C# script to my local server. There should be a PHP script which reply on this post request and give data from mysql data base in json form back. But how can the PHP script reply on a HTTP Post from my client?

Comment: As it replies to an HTTP post from any other client. Either check the superglobal post array and echo the data using `json_encode` or setup a data stream using any protocol you wish. You could also set up a SOAP wrapper for easier access.

Comment: Have you any website where there is a good tutorial? Lets say I made a post request with c#, with my local website "http://*.*.*.*/test.php" and data like "thing1=test&thing2=example" and then I want as reponse a json string with data from my mysql data base. But with what kind of php code can I do such a reply for this http post? I already know the json_encode function and how this works with mysql connection.

Comment: Could this code work: `<?php $thing1= $_POST["thing1"]; $thing2 = $_POST["thing2"]; ?>` so that the variables $vorname have the data from my post request?

Comment: Yes, but you should do some input validation and use Prepared Statements to query the database to prevent SQL injection hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a post request, the most basic setup to return JSON data is the following:

You can use parameters as an array:

```
192.*.*.*/test.php?thing[0]=test&thing[1]=example

192.*.*.*/test.php?thing[key-a]=test&thing[key-b]=example
```

or use single parameters:

```
192.*.*.*/test.php?thing1=test&thing2=example
```

I recommend the first method, since it is more flexible when you like to add further parameters.

```
<?php

if( empty( $_POST ) ) {
    // exit the script if there is no post data
    return;
}

// using parameters as array:

// filter empty values ('', 0) from array, if necessary
$_POST = array_filter( $_POST );

// reading array parameters
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {

    // retrieve your parameters here
    $column = $key;
    $value = trim( $value );

    // and query the database
    $results = PDO::fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

}

// output JSON; $results could be an array as retrieved through PDO::fetchAll()
echo json_encode( $results );


// or using single parameters:

if( !empty( $_POST['thing1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['thing2'] ) ) {

    // query the database
    $results = PDO::fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

}
```

Comment: @user3493797 I've yet again updated the script to exit if there is no post data at all, which is typically in the PHP world. (early function returns are preferred over large `else` blocks; this also works for a file scope `return;`)